# Update QSQLTableModel in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qsqltablemodel

I created one dialog that is used only to `bindValues` in a SQL database,
and I can save every new record sucessfully. The problem is that I've got another dialog with `QSQlTableModel` that only shows the information from the database. Every time I make a new record I must close the program and run it again to see the changes in the `ShowInformationDialog()`.
Do you know some way such that I don't need to close the program to update the information in my `ShowInformationDialog()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select()` method of `QSqlTableModel` class to repopulate the model with data from the database. Bound views get updated automatically. I suggest connecting a signal from wherever you update the data in the database (i.e. your dialog updating the SQL database) to custom slot in your `ShowInformationDialog()` that calls the `select()` of the `QSqlTableModel` object. I assume you have a `QMainWindow` object that is parent of both dialogues which would be most likely the best place to establish the connection.

Also since your `ShowInformationDialog()`'s model is only used for viewing the data consider using `QSqlQueryModel`. If that is used then `setQuery()` method should be used instead of `select()` but otherwise (the connection of a signal to `ShowInformationDialog()`'s slot) it would be the same.